# when I am running my chef-client with the code : [root@ip-172-31-33-62 cookbook]# chef-client -zr "recipe[test-cookbook::test-recipe]"

Tags: chef-client

`Running handlers: [2023-07-09T03:24:31+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers Running handlers complete [2023-07-09T03:24:31+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete Infra Phase failed. 0 resources updated in 02 seconds [2023-07-09T03:24:31+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /root/.chef/local-mode-c                                                                             ache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out [2023-07-09T03:24:31+00:00] FATAL: ---------------------------------------------                                                                             ------------------------------------------ [2023-07-09T03:24:31+00:00] FATAL: PLEASE PROVIDE THE CONTENTS OF THE stacktrace                                                                             .out FILE (above) IF YOU FILE A BUG REPORT [2023-07-09T03:24:31+00:00] FATAL: ---------------------------------------------                                                                             ------------------------------------------ [2023-07-09T03:24:31+00:00] FATAL: Net::HTTPServerException: 412 "Precondition F                                                                             ailed"`
`

==============
trying to resolve this .